# compile vlc for android

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I am trying to compile vlc for android in RHEL 6.4 (Santiago). I am following the instructions given in this page https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile. I am getting some errors.

First is when I build this, I get error in git.

```
error: unknown switch `B'. refer http://txt.do/6tjh for log
```

I changed the `git checkout -B android ${TESTED_HASH}` to `git checkout -b android ${TESTED_HASH}`. Then this error does not come

Then when I run sh compile.sh, I get following errors (refer http://tny.cz/bb552912 I have removed some part of log which had code to download packages like automake, protobuf, ragel etc)

```
rmdir: failed to remove /root/Documents/android/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include/freetype2/freetype/config': No such file or directory

make[1]: [install] Error 1 (ignored)

rmdir: failed to remove `/root/Documents/android/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include/freetype2/freetype': No such file or directory
make[1]: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Then if I again run sh compile.sh, weird things happen. I don't get this error again, but it builds some library and then stops.

First it build libdvdcss and then stops (refer http://tny.cz/5f3ab58f)
It ends like

Libraries have been installed in:
   /root/Documents/android/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during linking and do at least one of the following:

- add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable during execution
- add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
   during linking
- use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
- have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

---

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Documents/android/android/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-arm-linux-androideabi/dvdcss'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Documents/android/android/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-arm-linux-androideabi/dvdcss'
```

touch .dvdcss

Then each time I run "sh compile.sh" it build one more library and then stops.
it has build following libraries

1. libopenjpeg  (http://tny.cz/86236e8b)
2. libgpg-error   http://tny.cz/26c5626b)
3. ffmpeg         (http://tny.cz/1f05aa0f)
4. gmp
5. libgcrypt
6. iconv
7. nettle
8. libjpeg

Finally I get an following error and I am not able to do any after that (http://tny.cz/ed7798ea)

autopoint: * The AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION declaration in your configure.ac               file requires the infrastructure from gettext-0.18 but this version               is older. Please upgrade to gettext-0.18 or newer.

autopoint: * Stop.

autoreconf: autopoint failed with exit status: 1

configure.in:20: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL

```
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
```

autoreconf: /root/Documents/android/android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
make: *[.ogg] Error 1

I am not able to find gettext package with version > .18 for RHEL 6.4. Maximum available is .17 which is installed

1. Is not this weird. Should not doing "sh compile.sh" build all libraries and I should not have to do this again and again.
2. Also Is RHEL 6.4 (Santiago) compatible for building vlc android
3. Any help for these errors

Comment: Hi @pankaj : did you get solution of this , I am also getting the same error and stuck there

Comment: @ParikhVaibhav, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30350687/1893766 for building on Ubuntu (not RedHat).

Comment: @ozbek : Thanks for sharing  , I was able to compile it with one of friends' help on Ubuntu 15.04 (requires latest version) as there were too many dependent libs were missing from my system(Ubuntu 12).