# VLC Android Studio Compile Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, libvlc

I am trying to get VLC code into android studio but I facing lot's of difficulties doing that. I am on Windows and I got VLC source code from below repo. I also Installed NDK too.

Url : git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git

Can anyone let me know the process to successfully compile VLC project with android studio on windows really need this to be done.

Comment: Once import it gives this eror Error:CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Anyone can help ????

Comment: According to the official [VLC docs](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/), _You **MUST** build on Linux (or OSX if you know what you are doing)._ So, you are most probably out of luck. For building on Linux, see the aforementioned page and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30350687/1893766

Comment: I figure out a way to compile the code @Ozbek I will update it here once I completely tested it cheers!!!! Anyway thanks for the reply