# :libvlc:buildDebugARMv7 FAILED

Tags: android, c++, libvlc

I am trying to build in gradle using  the vlc for android as i follow this steps

[AndroidCompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/)

but I am getting error in building.

see the image

[image]

I downloaded the latest android sdk for linux and NDK

can you help me please how to fix this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please install following package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ant autoconf automake autopoint cmake gawk gcc g++ libtool m4 patch pkg-config libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c0-dev protobuf-c-compiler ragel subversion unzip
```

For more details please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350687/2579281)